# Cannot find mockito in instrumentation test

Tags: android, unit-testing, mockito

Okay, I might be really dumb here but I cannot import mockito into my instrumentation test.
Here is a screenshot of my instrumentation test class which simply cannot find mockito package.

[image: Mockito error]

And here is my complete build.gradle file

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
}
}
repositories {
jcenter()
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.trendingrepo"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1"
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation('org.mockito:mockito-android:2.6.3') {
    exclude group: 'org.hamcrest', module: 'hamcrest-core'
}
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
androidTestImplementation('org.droidparts.dexmaker:dexmaker:1.5') {
    exclude module: 'objenesis'
}
}
```

Comment: Go to File > Sync Project With Gradle Files

Comment: @Squti I even did Invalidate caches and restart, even restarted the mac :(

Comment: use  testImplementation  "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.15.0"

Comment: Although now it gives a really weird issue. Mockito can only mock non-private & non-final classes. And my class is already public and non-final. This is really irritating now.

Comment: You'll probably want to edit your question or ask a new question if you need help with your specific test.

Comment: @second Not sure what part of my question makes you think that I need help with any specific test. I tried to be clear as much as possible by uploading a screenshot of the build error I'm facing.

Comment: I read your previous comment `... now it gives a really weird issue` as that you still have not solved your entire problem (besides the build issue).